# How to implement infinite scroll in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, pagination, rxdart

How to implement infinite scroll in Flutter?
The list I get from the server has pagination. How can I get the data page by page from the server and implement it with infinite scrolling?

I want to implement this feature with good performance

Comment: Please post with code that you have tried so far. Or else for idea, use the search box and you'll get lots of duplicate questions on SO.